# Can I get Bundler to share Git-based gems across projects?

Tags: ruby, git, bundler

Without the gemsets provide by a tool like RVM, all gem installations are global. So if two projects use the same version of Ruby, and both have identical gemfiles, I would expect that running `bundle install` for the first one would install the gems, then running `bundle install` for the second would be able to use the already-downloaded gems to satisfy its requirements.

However, this doesn't appear the be the case with gems that are located in Github repos. For example, I have several projects with identical gem references, similar to this:

```
gem 'some_gem', git: 'git@github.com/me/some_gem.git', ref: 'a293bkd9d23'
```

Yet, although `bundle install` in one project clearly has to download this particular commit, it seems that `bundle install` in the next project repeats that process.

Bundler does not appear to store these Git-based gems in `~/.gem` with my normal gems.

Where does it put them, and can I make it check for the specified commit locally before fetching from the repo again?

Comment: Partial answer: it puts them in a folder like `~/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/some_gem-a293bkd9d23`. If an app relies on that version, and I move that folder, `bundle check` is unsatisfied, but if I move it back, `bundle check` is satisfied again. But in that case, I would think the second app could look there and be satisfied without fetching the repo again...

Comment: It should probably do that... are you sure it actually performs a git clone, or is it just checking for updates and such with git fetch?